# How to split a NSString based on characters markers?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Below is an NSString I am getting from a webservice:

```
"You invited @testaccount,Peter,richie@ to WonUp $#book$"
```

I need the strings `testaccount,Peter,richie` into an NSArray, and `#book` (ie. the part of the string within the `$` markers) into another NSArray.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
NSString *str = @"@testaccount,Peter,richie@ to WonUp $#book$";
NSArray* arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" to WonUp "];
NSString *str1;
NSArray* arr1;
if (arr.count > 0) {
    str1 = [[arr objectAtIndex:0]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@""];
    arr1 = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
}
NSString *str2;
if (arr.count > 1) {
    str2 = [[arr objectAtIndex:1]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
}
NSLog(@"%@ %@",str2,arr1);
```